# No space between columns using the Flex Box Grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Using the [Flex Box Grid system](http://flexboxgrid.com/). What is the correct way of removing the spacing between two 50% width columns?

Is there a standard class available for this? I can't find one on the official website.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            col 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            col 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

**1) If you need to remove the row-column spacing (gutters) globally**

You can directly change the `:root` variables in flexboxgrid.css or override them in your custom css file.

```
:root {
    --gutter-compensation: 0; // remove negative margins for row
    --half-gutter-width: 0; // remove padding from columns
}
```

**2) You can use a utility class, if you need to remove spacing only in a specific section**

Borrowing the concept from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), you can just add a class which removes negative margin from `.row` and padding from `.col-*`,

```
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Then add `.no-gutters` class with `.row`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            col 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            col 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the second option most. Using a utility class makes it very flexible. Also good to know that there also is a :root variable in case all spacing could be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this grid system, but I can see from inspecting the elements in my browser's dev tools that the space between elements is created with the padding-right and padding-left properties.  You could try adding another class name to your nested elements, and write rules for that class which override the padding-right and padding-left.

The css would look something like this.  Your selector should have a higher specificity than the selectors applied by Flex Box Grid System.  If you need to learn about specificity, here is a good guide: https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

```
.container .row .noPadding {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

The html would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="noPadding col-md-6">
            col 1
        </div>
        <div class="noPadding col-md-6">
            col 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could refrain from applying classes from the Flex Box Grid System on the two elements that you don't want spaced, and just use the css spec's flex property.  Here is a concise guide to css flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `child-no-padding` class in the `row` div:

```
.child-no-padding>div {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

By this way you prevent from repetitive `no-padding` class name in the child elements.

**Sample:**

```css
.child-no-padding>div {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.col-2{
    background: #00fff5; border: 1px solid #6cccca; text-align:center; font-size:.8em; color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row child-no-padding">
    <div class="col-2">
      col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      col 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Why the use of !important here? I like to avoid that statement because it's too radical. It completely throws the cascading effect of css out of the window.

Comment: @Floris. I just want make sure other classes in your project that I don't know them dose not any side effect on this implement in your project but it is not necessary if you see the code works well without it in your project.